# NodeJs - Out of range exception on file upload

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using NodeJs to create a WebApp with the purpose of uploading files on a server.

I am using *Express-FileUpload*, sending files using js-FormData(), from client to API (NodeJS), and then processing the file.
Everything is going okay, except when I select a file above certain size, for example 2.15 GB file.
I am receiving this error message:

> internal/validators.js:90
> throw new ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE(name, `>= ${min} && <= ${max}`, value);
> ^
>
> RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "length" is out of range.
> It must be >= 0 && <= 2147483647. Received 2305039912
> at Function.concat (buffer.js:559:5)
> at getBuffer (D:\FileSharing_System\node_modules\express-fileupload\lib\memHandler.js:17:34)
> at complete (D:\FileSharing_System\node_modules\express-fileupload\lib\memHandler.js:37:14)
> at FileStream. (D:\FileSharing_System\node_modules\express-fileupload\lib\processMultipart.js:104:17)
> at FileStream.emit (events.js:322:22)
> at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1187:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {   code: 'ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE' }

I am using 64bit NodeJs, on a 64 bit Windows OS.
Is there any way to handle this kind of exception, any ideas ?

Comment: try using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Comment: What version of node? The error indicates the max value for a 32 bit integer (2147483647) so can you include the contents of `node --version` and `node -e 'console.log(process.env)'`?

Comment: Hi doublesharp, I mentioned in the question that I am running 64 bit node js,

Comment: But the node is installed on :\\Program Files (x86).. Can this be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that when you are not using temp files on Express-File-Upload, the binary buffer is being created on memory.
I tried using the express file upload config property :

```
app.use(fileUpload({
    useTempFiles: true,
    tempFileDir: "/tmp/"
}));
```

Now, the error is not appearing.